# Clear ListBox Selection when empty area is clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

At least one item always remain selected in ListBox. I want that when user clicks empty area of ListBox, selection should be cleared. How to do this?

I am trying to replicate Opera Notes as a part of my application. First i was using a binded DataGridView now i am using a binded ListBox on left pane

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Handle the ListBox.MouseDown event.

Call ListBox.IndexFromPoint, passing the Location property from the MouseDown event's MouseEventArgs parameter.

This should return the index of the item that was clicked, or ListBox.NoMatches if the click was on an empty area.

If the return value is ListBox.NoMatches, set the ListBox.SelectedIndex property to -1 to clear the selection.

Comment: Thanks! I did it with listbox, can i do the same with datagrid view?

Comment: Note that you don't have to create a new handler for MouseDown just to get the MouseEventArgs.  In your existing Click handler, you can cast e to a new MouseEventArgs variable, and get Location from that.

Answer (score 2):

Mr. Avalanchis has answered the question already. I am just adding the code necessary to follow the steps what he has suggested. Hope the explicit code will help.

```
private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point pt = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
        int index = listBox1.IndexFromPoint(pt);

        if (index <= -1)
        {
            listBox1.SelectedItems.Clear();
        }


    }
```